# Getting typescript compiler and live-server to play well together?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I'm working with Angular2 and typescript but I'm running into frustrations in my dev process.

I'm using `tsc -w` to watch for file changes and immediately compile. This can take 2 or 3 seconds to complete as it compiles all files that reference a changed file.

I'm using `live-server . --ignorePattern=.*\.ts` so that [live-server](https://github.com/tapio/live-server) can watch for non-ts file changes and update the browser to reflect the changes. Ideally it should force the browser to update when `tsc` is done compiling.

What ends up happening is that `tsc` will immediately build a .ts file on change and emit it's .js and .js.map files. This will trigger `live-server` to update. Then `tsc` will recompile all files that `import` the changed .ts file and emit all of their .js and .js.map files. This takes nearly 2 seconds to do. After that `live-server` refreshes the browser again.

If I change my `live-server` line to `live-server . --wait=3000 --ignore-pattern=.*\.ts` then it waits 3 seconds after the second emission of js files which means it waits an entire 5 seconds (2 seconds of compiling files that reference the changed file + 3 extra seconds of waiting) which can be quite cumbersome if a bunch of small changes are made back to back. It'll compile all the way back to my `boot.js` file.

Are there any `tsc` options/flags I can use to only emit compiled files once? I do not want to emit just one .js file but I'm open to other solutions.

Comment: [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript) npm module has support for incremental compilations and that should speed up your build process.

Comment: what was the solution you ended up adopting

Comment: @born2net I ended up ditching live-server for another reason. I need to proxy my API requests to a different server so I use [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)'s -P flag to do that. I'm just refreshing the page after I make changes. It may be a slight annoyance, but I'm in control and it's not refreshing twice.

Comment: I see, I ended up using jspm, its amazing, I highly recommend it. it compiles ts in the browser so the workflow in dev is super fast, practically real time with no waits

Comment: I had these two playing well together for a few days, then it suddenly stopped.

live-server will recognize that a file has been updated, looks like it is building it, but never outputs a new .js file.